# Вывод индексов массива

Tags: массивы, ruby

Задача (викибукс):

Вывести индексы массива в том порядке, в котором соответствующие им элементы образуют возрастающую последовательность.

Мое решение:

```
x = Array.new( 20 ) { rand }   #Создаем массив с рандомными элементами
#puts x                        #Вывод делал себе
#puts "\n"

y = x.sort                     #Сортировка массива, записываем в другой для
                               #наглядности. Я знаю про !
#puts y                        #Вывод делал себе
#puts "\n"

i = 0

begin                            #цикл
    l = y[i]                     #переменная равная элементу сортированного массива
    m = x.index{|elem|elem==l}   #поиск соответствующей переменной в начальном
    #puts "#{i} .. #{m}"            #Вывод делал себе
    puts m
    i = i+1                      #инкремент индекса (i += 1)
end while (i<20)                 #условие завершения
```

Но мне почему-то кажется, что в руби должно быть более простое решение.
Эта же мысль у меня была, пока пытался сделать rand(100). При повторяющихся элементах индексы тоже будут повторяться, а некоторых может и не быть :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = Array.new(10){ rand 20 }
=> [2, 11, 4, 3, 11, 19, 7, 13, 13, 9]
```

Если на выходе требуется получить массив такого же размера, но с другими данными, значит эти данные нужно в него поместить при помощи `.map`.
`.with_index` добавляет в блок к любому итератору индекс элемента.

```
a.map.with_index{ |e, i| [e, i] }.sort_by{ |e, i| e }.map{ |e, i| i }
=> [0, 3, 2, 6, 9, 4, 1, 8, 7, 5]
```

Для превращения полученного при помощи `.map.with_index` итератора в массив для дальнейшей обработки можно воспользоваться вызовом метода `.to_a`.

```
a.map.with_index.to_a.sort_by{ |e, i| e }.map{ |e, i| i }
=> [0, 3, 2, 6, 9, 4, 1, 8, 7, 5]
```

Во втором замыкании после запятой Ruby позволяет поставить сразу вертикальную черту, потому что нас интересует только первая переменная в каждом элементе массива.
А если нам не интересны переменные идущие в начале, то их придется разыменовать, и принято для этого использовать символ подчеркивания.

```
a.map.with_index.to_a.sort_by{ |e, | e }.map{ |_, i| i }
```

Можно записать еще короче, но не всегда это имеет смысл -- тут следует думать о смысле данных в массивами, которыми оперируешь, и каково потенциальное развитие кода программы.

```
a.map.with_index.to_a.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вам нужно `.each_with_index`

```
y.each_with_index {|k, v| p "#{k} => #{v}" }
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как мне это поможет. Ассоциативный массив всё равно не создается. http://pastebin.com/kLYfL5HE

Тогда уже проще использовать то, что во второй части на pastebin. Потом сделать array.sort, и как-то вывести только ключи. Хотя при сортировке это становится массивами в массиве ( [[x,y],[q,w],... )

Но это всё равно слишком сложно. Ruby во многом весьма прост. Мне казалось должно быть что-то простое и для таких вещей.